# In cordova-imagePicker I want to get the captured date of image and not the uploaded date in iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, imagepicker

I am working in iOS and after selecting the images, I get the temp path of all the selected images in success callback method. Then I call window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() on the selected paths to get the FileEntry object and then, I call the file() of FileEntry to get the File object. The File object has a property lastModifiedDate which returns the current date. I need the captured date of the image.
For example, if the image was captured two years back, I want that date not the current date.

Plugin: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

```
function onSuccess(filePathArray)
{
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePathArray[0], function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function(file){
            console.log(file.lastModifiedDate);
        });
    });
}
```